# Remove Paint from outdoor metal sill of Main Door

Tags: doors, paint, metal, removal, sill

So I guess when the door was painted 10 years ago, paint might of spilled on the metal sill? I'm not sure if that is the correct word for it. But I've taken a picture of it for reference.

[image]

I've attempted to use paint thinner to remove the paint, but it doesn't come off.

Anyone have suggestions? Is there a specific way i'm supposed to use paint thinner? I just put some on a rag and scrubbed as hard as I could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if this is an anodized aluminum sill (thats what it looks like), try using brake fluid.  it will destroy just about any paint bond out there.  just wipe up afterwards and degrease with a good quality degreaser.

be wary though, if its anything else other that anodized aluminum (or an other uncoated metal), the brake fluid will destroy the coating (even powdercoating will be toast)

if its vinyl, try cleaning it up with paint thinner and a toothbrush.  it may take some time but it usually works.  oven cleaners with sodium hydroxide in them also do a good job without damaging the vinyl.

Comment: Anodized Aluminum sill. How would I know. How could I figure this out?

Comment: is it metal or plastic (scratch it and see if a shiny spot shows up).  if metal, put a magnet on it.  if it sticks, steel - and therefore painted or powdercoated.  if not, likely aluminum and probably anodized.  try the brake fluid on  a small spot first and see if it eats the coating.

Comment: it's 100% metal, put a magnet to it. It didn't interact at all. Ok thanks.

Comment: If the magnet didn't stick than it's not steel & if you scratched at it & it showed a shinny silver color than it's probably aluminum, if it showed a shinny yellow color than its brass & a shinny reddish color than its copper & a shinny brown color bronze.

Answer (score 0):

Install new sill if you can it is usually attached with screws.
If you remove the paint with time the aluminum will oxidize.

To prevent this and keep it shiny, get paint remover masking tape a cheap brush and a small bag of stainless wool get the one with different sizes and get a spay bottle of clear coat in the paint dept.Also you need rubber gloves. Small wire brush.

Protect all area with masking tape , shake well remover before opening and also open covering with a rag , be careful , I always open the bottle first to remove gases you know that build inside the can, close back and shake, then brush a little at the time to no overflow you will see bubbling after few minutes paint could be removed , brush again the remover and continue cleaning the done wash with soap and water finish with de-greaser rinse well , dry very well cover surrounding area use masking tape old news paper, shake clear coat well 3 minutes at least follow this to get better results, when painting about 8 ,10 inches apart from surface from one end to the other pass once one way and once the other , let rest 5 minutes repeat al least 5 times to get good thickness , let dry. Avoid windy days.